# CSS img[Attributes Style]

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having a problem in Wordpress and CSS. I want to enable my images to be the full width of my posts (800px) but right now they are being capped at 620px. When I go in to Inspect Element, this is the CSS code I'm getting:

```
img[Attributes Style] {
    width: 640px;
    height: 427px;
}
```

In Inspect Element, this block of code is grayed out and I can't edit it. What is this? What is the [Attributes Style]. In Wordpress's CSS Editor I've added code for img max-width: 800px, but this has no effect. I've also tried img width: 800px, but this forces ALL images to be 800px.

Please help! Thanks! :)

Comment: why not target those image: `.containerClass img {width:100%}` where containerClass is the class of the div / article element wrapping each post

Answer (score 4):

It's because it has a width and height set on the image via attributes.

```html
<img src="/path/to/image.png" width="800" height="400" />
```

You can add some CSS to your stylesheet (as opposed to any JavaScript or PHP fix to remove the attributes from the image tag) to make it full width of the container.

```css
.image-container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%
}

.image-container img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: So, the problem is that when I use width: 100%, it forces and scales all images to be 800px, not just the ones that are actually above the current 640px limit. Here is my site btw: http://vintagevalueinvesting.com/fascinating-look-dr-michael-burrys-investment-strategy/. I'm trying to get the first image of the guy standing at the desk to be 800px (which it is, it's just not displaying that way) while keep all the other images their current size (all less than 800px).

Comment: Try changing width to auto instead and see how you get on.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I think there's something in my theme's files that is preventing images from being sized larger than 640px, and I can't overrule it through CSS. I don't know which php file it would be though. :/

Comment: I've updated the code example above. Try that but have a look in developer tools and see if anything else is doing anything to the image sizes. What theme are you using?

Comment: Still doesn't work...The problem is this in the HTML for the image: <img class="size-full wp-image-5580 aligncenter" src="https://i0.wp.com etc. etc. **sizes="(max-width: 640px)** 100vw, 640px" width="640" height="427">'.... I don't know how to change that "sizes="max-width: 640px" and I don't think the CSS is able to override it. The theme I'm using is Point for Wordpress, but I modified the CSS to make the margins wider which is what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I went to Wordpress>>Customize>>Additional CSS and then there was a box that said Media Width. I set this to 825 and it fixed it! Not sure where in my CSS code this applied but now it works. Thanks Daniel and Pete for your help anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for custom logo width and height change

Theme -> Function.php

And then find

```
//Logo support
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'height'      => 78,
    'width'       => 445,
    'flex-height' => true,
) );
```

Here you can change the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

add [this code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) in functions.php file and change the width number

```
if(!isset($content_width)) {
  $content_width = 825;
}
```